# How can i place all API calls in one JS file and How it can be used in a component to use the content coming from the API

Tags: api, vue.js

I am new to vuejs, i am using different components, and in every components i have made a API call, the API used is similar in every components, but only change in id i.e. if API is **/contents/info/[id]**, I have used the respective id for the respective component.

But in order to make it effective, i have few questions regarding that:

1.How can i put the /contents/info/[id] API in a JS file, where [id] should be the argument. If i want to make an API call in any component i just want to use the id.

2.After making a API call in a JS file, i want to know how it can be used in any component by their respective id ?

Please do help me, because i have many APIs which only differs by id. And i want to make it effective by just creating a single JS file and dumping all the APIs with arguments and then importing that to a respective component and use it by their respective id.

Comment: Services are that u need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create an api_service and put in plugins(or another folder like utils or services if you want) folder and inject that to all of you and config that in your nuxt.config.js. like below:

index.js in plugins folder:

```
var _this
export default function ({ app }, inject) {
_this = app
inject('ApiService', ApiService)
}

const ApiService = {
post (resource, params) {
 return _this.$axios.$post(`${resource}`, params)
 }
}
```

and you can access it in all of your project.